# Возвращение мнимого адреса из стека

Tags: c, стек

Добрый день!
На некотором ресурсе были найдены такие строчки кода:

```
 *(char **)(if_.esp) = (if_.esp + 4); if_.esp -= 4;
 *(int *)(if_.esp) = argc; if_.esp -= 4;
 *(int *)(if_.esp) = 0;
```

В комментариях значилось что это "возврат мнимого адреса из стека".
Ранее производилась передача аргументов программы в этот самый стек.
Помогите понять (желательно дословно объясняя каждую операцию), что означают эти строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для начала понимания нужно сделать одну замену - `if_.esp` -> `p`. И разберем по строкам.

```
*(char **)p= (p + 4);
p -= 4;
*(int *)p = argc;
p -= 4;
*(int *)p = 0;
```

теперь стает понятнее. по некому адресу, который храниться в p (раньше это был `if_.esp`) записывается этот же адрес, увеличенный на 4. После чего указатель уменьшается на 4. Следующим этапом по этому новому адресу (`p-4`) записывается argc. Точно также по адресу `p-8` записывается 0.

То есть, грубо говоря, это просто

```
push p+4
push argc
push 0
```

правда там не хватает ещё одной строки с `p -= 4`, но ее либо съел оптимизатор, либо Вы.

Если посмотреть на это с большей высоты, то это просто симуляция ассемблерного вызова  call (вначале в стек записывается адрес следующей инструкции, потом два аргумента).  Имя `esp` как бы на это и намекает.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо.
А зачем это:
"по некому адресу, который храниться в p записывается этот же адрес, увеличенный на 4." ?

Да и, Вы правы, строчка p -= 4 там была)

Comment: Зачем? что бы потом команда `ret` правильно отработала. Когда выполнение процедуры закончиться и она "поправит стек" (то есть, достанет оттудова все параметры и/или увеличит `if_.esp` на 8 (два параметра по 4), то со стека можно будет взять адрес возврата.

Зачем это нужно? а как по другому сделать вызов процедуры? Адрес для возврата все равно нужно запоминать. Но вот только в таком случае (с записью в стек) очень легко сделать рекурсию.

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо!